# NullPointer Exception Jcreator, Java

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, jcreator

I am having an incredibly difficult time trying to figure out why I am getting this error.
When I use a driver file to test the program it fails horribly.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math.*;
public class Histogram
{
private int[] arrayData;
private int[] arrayRange;
private final int LOW = 1;
private final int HIGH = 100;

    public Histogram()
     {
        int[] arrayData = new int[11];
     }

    public void getInput()
    {
        int[] arrayRange = new int[11];
        for(int count = 1; count < arrayRange.length; count++)
            {
                arrayRange[count] = count * 10;
            }
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter numbers from 1 to 100, Type -999 to quit.");
        int nextNumb = input.nextInt();
        while(nextNumb != -999)
        {
            if(nextNumb >= LOW && nextNumb <= HIGH)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i <= arrayRange.length; i++)
                {
                if(nextNumb > arrayRange[i] && nextNumb <= arrayRange[i+1])
                    arrayData[i]++;
                }
                nextNumb = input.nextInt();
            }
            else arrayData[10]++;
            nextNumb = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public String starPrint(double count)
    {
        String star = "";
        count = (Math.round(count) / 5);
        for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            star = star + "*";
        }

        return star;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String results = " Range   |   Histogram"  + "\n";
        results = results + "1 - 10 | " + starPrint(arrayData[0]) + "\n";
        results = results + "11 - 20 | " + starPrint(arrayData[1]) + "\n";
        results = results + "21 - 30 | " + starPrint(arrayData[2]) + "\n";
        results = results + "31 - 40 | " + starPrint(arrayData[3]) + "\n";
        results = results + "41 - 50 | " + starPrint(arrayData[4]) + "\n";
        results = results + "51 - 60 | " + starPrint(arrayData[5]) + "\n";
        results = results + "61 - 70 | " + starPrint(arrayData[6]) + "\n";
        results = results + "71 - 80 | " + starPrint(arrayData[7]) + "\n";
        results = results + "81 - 90 | " + starPrint(arrayData[8]) + "\n";
        results = results + "91 - 100 | " + starPrint(arrayData[9]) + "\n";
        results = results + "Outliers: " + starPrint(arrayData[10]) + "\n";
        return results;
    }
}
```

I believe that the problem is in my getInput method
right here to be precise:

```
if(nextNumb > arrayRange[i] && nextNumb <= arrayRange[i+1])
    arrayData[i]++;
```

I have no idea what's wrong with it though I am a beginner programmer and couldn't find a solution to this particular problem.
Thanks for any help you're able to give!

Comment: Can you share the complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Histogram()
{
   int[] arrayData = new int[11];
}
```

You're *shadowing* your `arrayData` field in the constructor. This is creating a local variable with the same name as your class's `arrayData` field, initializing it, then immediately discarding it. When you try to use the field later in your code, it's `null`. Get rid of the `int[]` part.

Note that your next exception will be an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ... you should look at your loop ;)

Comment: look at my answer for the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` problem

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

this: `for(int i = 0; i <= arrayRange.length; i++)`
wont work since you are trying to access `arrayRange[i]` and `arrayRange[i+1]`

which dont exists for `i = arrayRange.length-1` and further

so change it to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayRange.length-1; i++)
```

Comment: Thank you haha you saved me alot of hair pulling!